# Ajax Request issue with ASP.NET MVC 4 Area

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, jquery, asp.net-mvc-areas

Today i discovered something weird, i have regular asp.net mvc 4 project with no such ajax (just post, get). so today i need ajax request, i did an ajax action with jquery in controller and it didn't work out. Here is my code

Areas/Admin/Controllers/BannersController

```
    public JsonResult SaveOrder(string model)
    {
        bool result = false;

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(model))
        {
            var list = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<int>>(model);

            result = repository.SaveOrder(list);
        }

        return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

View side (Its in area too)

```
        $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#saveOrder").click(function () {

            var data = JSON.stringify($("#list_banners").nestable('serialize'));

            $.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Action("SaveOrder", "Banners", new { area = "Admin" })',
                data: { model: data },
                success: function (result) {

                    if (result) {
                        toastr.success('Kaydedildi.');
                    }
                    else {
                        toastr.error('kaydedilemedi.');
                    }

                },
                error: function (e) {
                    console.log(e);
                }
            });

        });
    });
```

i've already tried everything i know, which is $.post, $.get, ajax options, trying request from out of area etc.. just request can't reach action

and here is the errors ,
http://prntscr.com/297nye

error object
http://prntscr.com/297o3x

Comment: Try telling ajax what datatype to expect, `datatype: 'json/application',
type: 'GET',`

Comment: same result, nothing's changed

Comment: @user2107255 Did you try to hit the url directly first using browser, atleast to make sure your routes are clear.. Also Your action is a GET action right?

Comment: Try to send a simple string, meaning `data: { model: "Hello World" },` and see if it calls the controller properly.  I have a feeling the problem lies in the stringification (?) of `data`

Comment: I have had more luck with post personally.  use what @Jose recommended but put post instead and add [HttpPost] to your controller

Comment: Thanks for comments, @PSL yes its working when i put url to browser. Jose i did breakpoint in controller for maybe data giving problem but not when i make new action with no data its not working too. Matt Bodily yes i have test it too, still same result

Answer (score 2):

Try by specifying the data format (json) you wand to post to server like and Also change the way you pass data object in JSON like this :

```
 var data = $("#list_banners").nestable('serialize');

     $.ajax({
              url: '@Url.Action("SaveOrder", "Banners", new { area = "Admin"    })',
              data: JSON.stringify({ model: data }),
              dataType: 'json',
              contentType: "application/json",
               ...
```

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue, but after spending too much time, got solution for that. If your request is going to your specified controller, then check your response. There must be some problem in your response. In my case, response was not properly converted to JSON, then i tried with passing some values of response object from controller using select function, and got what i needed.